# Draw shapes by konva to be displayed in canvas

Tags: vue.js, konva, vue-konva

I want to use konva in vue.js to draw shapes to be displayed in a canvas, so i have some rectangles stored in rectangles array which need to be drawn, but no thing is drawn.

```
<template>
<div>
  <Button id="b1" @click="promp()" style="background:url(/squ.png)"></Button>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;" @click="detectclick($event)">
      <v-rect
          v-for="item in rectangles"
          :key="item.id"
          :config="item"
          @transformend="handleTransformEnd($e,rectangles)"
        />
        <v-transformer ref="transformer" />
  </canvas>
 
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put `vue-konva` components inside `<canvas>` element.

All `vue-konva` components are designed to work only inside `<v-layer` component, which should be placed inside `<v-stage>`. For understanding, Konva nodes structure take a look into [Konva Overview](https://konvajs.org/docs/overview.html).

```html
<v-stage :config="{width: 500, height: 500}">
  <v-layer>
    <v-rect
      v-for="item in rectangles"
      :key="item.id"
      :config="item"
      @transformend="handleTransformEnd($e,rectangles)"
    />
  </v-layer>
</v-stage>
```